# Addrees field validation label not showing required mark

Tags: magento-2.1, validation, form-validation

Hi i have a shipping address form with fields like following image. In which street address field is required field but it don't have star mark.

[image]

I want to add red star after label but i didn't found the form. Any help appreciated.